# Zend OPcache class loading error

Tags: symfony, composer-php, php-5.5, opcache

Every so often, one of the instances in our application will start throwing this error:

`[Fri Aug 29 14:23:25.359848 2014] [:error] [pid 2759] [client 1.2.3.4:58627] PHP Fatal error:  Zend OPcache class loading error, class FSC\\HateoasBundle\\Serializer\\EventSubscriber\\EmbedderEventSubscriber in /var/app/current/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 183`

It happens when loading any page. I've tried `composer dump-autoload`, but that does nothing. Repeatedly restarting Apache is equally useless. This is PHP 5.5.7 running on Apache 2.4.6. Here's the opcache preferences:

```
[root@ip-1-2-3-4 html]# php -i | grep opc
/etc/php-5.5.d/opcache.ini,
opcache.blacklist_filename => /etc/php-5.5.d/opcache*.blacklist => /etc/php-5.5.d/opcache*.blacklist
opcache.consistency_checks => 0 => 0
opcache.dups_fix => Off => Off
opcache.enable => On => On
opcache.enable_cli => Off => Off
opcache.enable_file_override => Off => Off
opcache.error_log => no value => no value
opcache.fast_shutdown => 1 => 1
opcache.file_update_protection => 2 => 2
opcache.force_restart_timeout => 180 => 180
opcache.inherited_hack => On => On
opcache.interned_strings_buffer => 8 => 8
opcache.load_comments => 1 => 1
opcache.log_verbosity_level => 1 => 1
opcache.max_accelerated_files => 4000 => 4000
opcache.max_file_size => 0 => 0
opcache.max_wasted_percentage => 5 => 5
opcache.memory_consumption => 256 => 256
opcache.optimization_level => 0xFFFFFFFF => 0xFFFFFFFF
opcache.preferred_memory_model => no value => no value
opcache.protect_memory => 0 => 0
opcache.restrict_api => no value => no value
opcache.revalidate_freq => 2 => 2
opcache.revalidate_path => Off => Off
opcache.save_comments => 1 => 1
opcache.use_cwd => On => On
opcache.validate_timestamps => On => On
```

We're all at a loss as to what's going on. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'd speculate you are experiencing some bug inside the Zend Opcache module. These usually are hard to track down because the opcode cache contains the script code that PHP really executes, and this cache is filled with the opcodes of the first execution of every file. If this is somehow broken, it will fail even though the PHP source code you are looking at is correct. If disabling the Opcache fixes the problem (beware the performance penalty!), you might want to fiddle with the optimization level next.